# Animating multiple Circles in each frames in Python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, animation

I am trying to create the animation in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k8FXF1KjzY0&t=26s) using Python. But I stuck on the very first step. Till now I've created a Circle and a point rotating around its circumference. My code is given below. Now I want to plot the `y` values corresponding to  `x=np.arange(0, I*np.pi, 0.01)` along the x-axis (as shown in `update()` function in the code). For this I have to define another function to plot these `x` and `y` and pass that function inside a new `animation.FuncAnimation()`.

Is there any way to plot everything using only the `update()` function?

**Note** I have found a code of this animation in [here](https://github.com/CodingTrain/website/blob/master/CodingChallenges/CC_125_Fourier_Series/P5/sketch.js). But it is written in Java!

**My Code**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import numpy as np


W = 6.5
H = 2
radius = 1
I = 2
T = 3
N = 2

plt.style.use(['ggplot', 'dark_background'])


def create_circle(x, y, r):
    circle = plt.Circle((x, y), radius=r, fill=False, alpha=0.7, color='w')
    return circle


def create_animation():

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-2, W + 2), ylim=(-H, H))

    circle = create_circle(0, 0, radius)
    ax.add_patch(circle)

    line1, = ax.plot(0, 1, marker='o', markersize=3, color='pink', alpha=0.7)

    def update(theta):
        x = radius * np.cos(theta)
        y = radius * np.sin(theta)

        line1.set_data([0, x], [0, y])

        return line1,


    anim = []
    anim.append(animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update,
                                        frames=np.arange(0, I * np.pi, 0.01),
                                        interval=10, repeat=True))

    # anim.append(animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_line, len(x),
    #                                     fargs=[x, y, line, line1], interval=10))

    plt.grid(False)
    plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
    plt.gca().spines['left'].set_visible(False)
    plt.gca().spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    plt.gca().spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    plt.gca().spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
    plt.gca().set_xticks([])
    plt.gca().set_yticks([])

    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    create_animation()
```

**Edit.** I've improved the task by defining a global variable `pos` and changing the `update()` function in the following manner ...The animation now looks better but still having bugs!

**Improved Portion**

```
    plot, = ax.plot([], [], color='w', alpha=0.7)
    level = np.arange(0, I * np.pi, 0.01)
    num = []
    frames = []
    for key, v in enumerate(level):
        num.append(key)
        frames.append(v)

    def update(theta):
        global pos
        x = radius * np.cos(theta)
        y = radius * np.sin(theta)
        wave.append(y)

        plot.set_data(np.flip(level[:pos] + T), wave[:pos])
        line1.set_data([0, x], [0, y])
        pos += 1

        return line1, plot,
```

**Edit** Till now I've done the following:

```
def update(theta):
    global pos
    x, y = 0, 0

    for i in range(N):
        prev_x = x
        prev_y = y

        n = 2 * i + 1
        rad = radius * (4 / (n * np.pi))
        x += rad * np.cos(n * theta)
        y += rad * np.sin(n * theta)
        wave.append(y)

        circle = create_circle(prev_x, prev_y, rad)
        ax.add_patch(circle)

        plot.set_data(np.flip(level[:pos] + T), wave[:pos])
        line2.set_data([x, T], [y, y])
        line1.set_data([prev_x, x], [prev_y, y])

        pos += 1

    return line1, plot, line2,
```

**Output**
[image]

Please help to correct this animation. Or, is there any efficient way to do this animation?

**Edit** Well, now the animation is partially working. But there is a little issue: In my code (inside the definition of `update()`) I have to add circles centered at `(prev_x, prev_y)` of radius defined as `rad` for each frame. For this reason I try to use a `for loop` in the definition of `update()` but then all the circles remains in the figure (see the output below). But I want one circle in each frame with the centre and radius as mentioned above. Also the same problem is with the `plot`. I try to use `ax.clear()` inside the `for loop` but it didn't work.

Comment: It seems you have found the solution to your problem as stated in the title of your question. It is unclear to me what is the question now. "Please help correct this animation" is not descriptive enough. Ask a question about a specific issue you are having

Comment: @DizietAsahi..I have edited my question.

Comment: I do have problems understanding the question as well. Maybe note that you can remove artists from a plot via `artist.remove()`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest......In the YouTube video that I've linked, there are circles spinning around the circumferences of previous one....How exactly do this .....?? This is the problem